# Google URL to subscribe to a calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

Similar to the [URL](https://dev.to/rinkiyakedad/creating-an-add-event-to-google-calendar-link-for-your-project-52c1) to add an event to someone's Google calendar, does anybody know if there's a URL that can let someone subscribe to an iCalendar URL containing multiple events?

Basically, I run a system with many events, and I'd like to give my users a simple one-click URL to bring ALL of those events into their calendar and subscribe to updates.

Currently, this is possible to do manually:

1. Open Google calendar
2. Select Other Calendars > Add > From URL
3. Enter URL and click Add Calendar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured it out but would love more information if anybody is more familiar with this.

NOTE: This doesn't seem to work with https URLs (but maybe that was just a problem with my local SSL cert)

## Solution:

Add `cid=<URL>` to the end of the main Google Calendar URL.

For example:

```
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r?cid=http://389d-50-215-20-6.ngrok.io/calendar.ics
```

Comment: I'm currently trying to do the same, I've found that this URL seems to work best: `https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?cid=webcal://389d-50-215-20-6.ngrok.io/calendar.ics`
note /calendar/render and webcal instead of http(s) but the issue I've ran in to is that if you click this link on a phone with google calendar installed it will open the app but wont sync the calendar which is very frustrating!

Comment: Works without specifying a protocol